# How to add app source code to xcode after downloading as a zip file from github

Tags: ios, xcode

Can anyone tell me how to add and open the moodle mobile app to Xcode?  I have downloaded the latest open source moodle mobile app as a zip file but not sure how to import or open this in xcode?

Basically want to open this in xcode, edit images and then be able to publish to the app store.

I have seen youtube videos showing github with a button called "open in xcode" but i don't see this in github as an option. The options that i get is to open in github desktop or download as zip.

https://github.com/moodlehq/moodleapp.git

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: it's in the documentation. find this file; platforms/ios/HelloWorld.xcworkspace/ and double click it. or open it from the command line with open platforms/ios/HelloWorld.xcworkspace/

Comment: Hi John, thanks for responding, i can't seem to find this workspace file. The path you gave does not exist.  I have downloaded the zip file, extracted it but cannot see such file? Any idea's?

Comment: You are right, I downloaded it and it's not there. You should post an issue on GitHub.